# Why doesn't WebView see JavaScript and sometimes crashes?

Tags: android, webview

I have a small app that tries to run `WebView` as follows:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_page, container, false);
    mWebView = v.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl(mUri.toString());

    return v;
}
```

When i try to run it on an API 24 device that doesn't have google services the `WebView` works, but for some reason doesn't enable JavaScript, even though `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` is used. When i try to perform the same on an API 24 device with google service, the `WebView` works well and can see JavaScript code. But the oddities don't end there...

In cases when i run the app on a devices that have API lower than 24 (i tried on 23 and 22) possession of google service doesn't influence JavaScript code processing by the `WebView`. In Either cases JavaScript doesn't work in the `WebView` for some reason.

API 25 has the same issues as 24 does.

API 26 bring something new. When i perform testing on a device with google services the works well. But without them the app just crashes while inflating writing to logcat the following:

```
E/WebViewFactory: Chromium WebView package does not exist
    android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException: Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewContextAndSetProvider(WebViewFactory.java:334)
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:398)
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:211)
        at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2467)
        at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2462)
        at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2527)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4536)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
        at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:636)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:581)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:564)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:551)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.bignerdranch.android.photogallery.PhotoPageFragment.onCreateView(PhotoPageFragment.java:41)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:248)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1333)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6992)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bignerdranch.android.photogallery, PID: 8470
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdranch.android.photogallery/com.bignerdranch.android.photogallery.PhotoPageActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.bignerdranch.android.photogallery.PhotoPageFragment.onCreateView(PhotoPageFragment.java:41)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:248)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1333)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6992)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException: Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:438)
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:211)
        at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2467)
        at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2462)
        at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2527)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4536)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
        at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:636)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:581)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:564)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:551)
            ... 35 more
     Caused by: android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException: Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewContextAndSetProvider(WebViewFactory.java:334)
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:398)
            ... 47 more
```

On API 27 devices the `WebView` can see JavaScript even if there are no google services.

All tests was performed on `Nexus 5X`.

In cases when `WebView` doesn't process JavaScript i tried to add the following code:

```
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

and also change the device to another one. Nothing of mentioned above fixed the problem.

So my questions are:

- **How google services impact possibility to see JavaScript for `WebView` ?**
- **Why can't `WebView` be inflated in API 26. It is placed in android so i have to be able to inflate it. Isn't it so ?**
- **And finally. How do i have to use `WebView` correctly so that it can see JavaScript and not get crashed across all API's ?**

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the `Fragment` or `Activity`, make sure that the `WebView` is installed or active.

```
public static boolean webViewEnabled() {
    try {
        return CookieManager.getInstance() != null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = ApplicationLoader.getContext().getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed = false;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        app_installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
    }
    return app_installed;
}
```

Checking if `WebView` is installed or active (you can even display a suitable response to the user:

```
if (!webViewEnabled()) {
    if (appInstalledOrNot("com.google.android.webview")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", "com.google.android.webview", null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (appInstalledOrNot("com.huawei.webview")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", "com.huawei.webview", null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (appInstalledOrNot("com.android.vending")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.webview"));
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (appInstalledOrNot("com.huawei.appmarket")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setPackage("com.huawei.appmarket");
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("appmarket://details?id=com.huawei.webview"));
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview"));
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            //
        }
    }
} else {
    // startActivity(new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class)) or ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, but in the cases, when `WebView` doesn't see JavaScript, `WebView` exists so unfortunately your solution will not help me.

Comment: Are your tests on the simulator? Also check appcompat:1.5.1 (unlikely but this might be useful).

Comment: I tested my app on the emulator and i already use `appcompat:1.5.1`

Comment: Different `JavaScript` version on android devices is also important, some new `JavaScript` features may not work on one device, so updating the `WebView` or putting a simple code in `JavaScript` for testing can be useful. Your code is correct and there is nothing wrong with it.